# load store for List using json

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here my code for list using Sencha touch2 , I have a rest service and I need to be able to load my store for my list view.Follows

```
var tab= Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                                width: 320,
                                height: 290,
                                store: {
                                fields: ['ext_xtype','imgURL','arimg'],
                                data: [{
                                       ext_xtype: 'Harry Potter 4',
                                       imgURL:'bo.png',
                                       arimg:'arrow.png'
                                       },{
                                       ext_xtype: 'Iphone5 64gb',
                                       imgURL:'mo.png',
                                       arimg:'arrow.png'
                                       },{
                                       ext_xtype: 'Hill Figure',
                                       imgURL:'wa.png',
                                       arimg:'arrow.png'
                                       }]
                                }, 
                                itemTpl: '<img src="{imgURL}" width="35" heigh="35"></img><span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{ext_xtype}<img src="{arimg}" width="25" height="25" align="right"></img>'
                                });
```

i have tried the following link [Sencha with proxy quest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887794/sencha-touch-load-store-for-list-using-rest-proxy) but couldnt help to proceed.Here the rest JSON method.

```
 Method: GET
 URL:  http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/ShowItems/userID=?
```

How shall i import the json to load in LIST

**#EDIT**

```
 var tab= Ext.create('Ext.List', {
                                width: 320,
                                height: 290,
                                //ui: 'round',
                                store: {
                                proxy: {
                                type: 'ajax',
                                url: 'http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/ShowItems/userID=1',
                                reader: {
                                type: 'json'
                                }
                                }
                                fields: [
                                         { imgURL: 'itemID' },
                                         { ext_xtype: 'itemName'},
                                         { arimg: 'itemImage'},
                                         ],
                                },
                                itemTpl: '<img src="{imgURL}" width="35" heigh="35"></img><span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp{ext_xtype}<img src="{arimg}" width="25" height="25" align="right"></img>'
                                });
```

[image: JSON REPONSE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had forgotten to set `root` and `idProperty` of JSON reader! It should be like below:

```
  proxy: {
  type: 'ajax',
  url: 'http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/ShowItems/userID=1',
  method: 'GET'
},
reader: {
  type: 'json',
  root: 'items',
  idProperty: 'itemID'
}
```

Besides, your JSON data should be as follows:

```
{"items": 
  [{
    "itemID": "1",  
    "errorMsg": "",  
    "itemName": "Airplane",  
    "itemDesc": "Model NEW 2003"
   },
   {
    "itemID": "2",  
    "errorMsg": "",  
    "itemName": "Bike",  
    "itemDesc": "Model NEW 2003"
   }
  ]
}
```